Is Testnet3 Addresses Support Segwit P2WSH P2WPKH transactions?

How Do I Know if My Bitcoin Address Is Segwit?

"Today, many Bitcoin wallets support SegWit by default. Bitcoin SegWit addresses typically start with a “3” or “bc1”.

Addresses starting with “3” are known as Pay to Script Hash (P2SH), which supports SegWit.
Addresses that begin with “bc1” are Bech32 addresses and represent native SegWit addresses that fully utilize the SegWit efficiency improvements.

If your address starts with “1”, it’s a legacy address and does not support SegWit."
My btc address "mguwz9PVtTrp11hzvp1atGBtTcFRvoHBCh" is this.
Does my btc address support segwit transactions?

It's Pay to Public Key Hash(P2PKH) testnet address, which doesn't support SegWit.
P2PKH address(legacy) which starts with “1”, starts with either "m" or "n" on testnet.
You can find the list of the prefix for address here.
